# Adding New Geometries Post-Finalize

Tags: drake

I'd like to be able to add or remove geometries as they appear/disappear in my environment.

The docs clearly state that all geometries must be added before the call to MultibodyPlant::Finalize(). Does this mean every time I add a new geometry, I have to re-create an entirely new plant/diagram/scene_graph and re-load all existing objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This strongly depends on the *role*.

`Proximity`: If you're using `MultibodyPlant` and are going to ask the plant to handle contact dynamics (e.g., `MultibodyPlant` needs to resolve contact), then the simplest answer is: you *cannot* change geometry after you finalize. Changes in geometry require new plants (as of *today*).

`Illustration` or `Perception`: If you're hoping to change the geometry for either of these roles, you can go into `SceneGraph` and manipulate those geometries to your hearts content before or after you finalize `MultibodyPlant`. If you're interested in this route, let me know in a comment and I'll elaborate on what this would look like in an edit.

Comment: Ah I see. Unfortunately I'm mainly interested in Proximity. Would this be a feasible change to request in a Github Issue in the near future? It sounds like many changes would be needed, but I feel this is an important issue. A robot's environment will constantly change, and constantly re-loading all scene meshes will be expensive. 

Maybe this is too complicated to answer here, but why should a newly added object conflict with the rest of the plant and scene graph? Can't a new body simply be added to the multibodytree? Is this due to some caching/pre-computations?

Comment: This happens to be *massive* topic. There are a few efforts documented for making the `MultibodyPlant` more flexible for "remodelling" (see [#13291](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/13291) and [#13298](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/13289) as examples). Finding an issue and weighing in on it is always a good way to help upvote backlog work.